# Emacs keybinding not working in custom major mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings, major-mode

I'm in the early stages of creating a [major mode for Emacs](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el) for browsing and interacting with the Stack Exchange Network.

Involved in it are several major modes, all with one-key keybindings similar to `dired`.  I looked at the source for `dired`, and extracted what I thought would work:

```
(defvar stack-network-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-keymap)))
    (define-key map "n"     'stack-network-next-site)
    (define-key map "p"     'stack-network-previous-site)
    (define-key map ","     'stack-network-move-site-up)
    (define-key map "."     'stack-network-move-site-down)
    (define-key map "j"     'stack-network-jump-to-bookmarks)
    (define-key map "\C-m"  'stack-network-do-enter-site) ; ret
    (define-key map "o"     'stack-network-do-enter-site)
    (define-key map "u"     'stack-network-do-profile-summary)
    (define-key map "\C-uu" 'stack-network-do-profile-summary-for-user)
    (define-key map "i"     'stack-network-do-inbox)
    (define-key map "b"     'stack-network-toggle-bookmark)
    (define-key map "?"     'stack-network-list-functions) ; [1]
    (define-key map "\C-i"  'stack-network-display-details) ; tab
    map)
  "Keymap for Stack Exchange: Network Browser major mode")
```

but unfortunately this seems to have absolutely no effect; the buffer is simply edited just as any other normal buffer would be.  How can I achieve single-key keybindings if this isn't they way? (Which, by the way, I'm sure it is.  There has to be something else going on here.)

Comment: Need more detail.... I load the package you refer to, and it works just fine.  All the major mode bindings are available (though undefined).

Comment: Don't define major modes with `defun`.  Use `define-derived-mode`, which handles all the boilerplate for you, including killing local variables, switching the key map, setting major mode vars, running the hooks, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to define `stack-network-mode` using `define-derived-mode` (and make it derive from `special-mode`, for example).

Other comments about your code:

- use `()` rather than `nil` for empty argument lists.
- stack-network-next-site needs to have `(interactive)` right after the docstring to make it an interactive command otherwise it won't work as a key-binding.

If you don't want to use `special-mode`, you can call `supress-keymap` right after creating your `make-keymap`.

Comment: This does prevent buffer editing (thanks to `special-mode`, I presume), but the keys are still not being bound :(  (Also, to my knowledge, `() === nil`.)

Comment: If you'd like to see the code as it stands, it's [here](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode/blob/71fb0081400bf71abf226fc6cb9e0382e2b7009a/elisp/stack-network-mode.el) (specific commit linked to preserve use for future reference)

Comment: @vermiculus `() === nil` holds, but it is convention to use `()` for empty argument lists.  `nil` at this place looks disturbing to most Emacs Lisp programmers.

Comment: @lunaryorn I'll keep that in mind -- I've mostly used it because it is much faster for me to type, and the idea of 'nil arguments' still makes sense.  But if it's convention we're after, I suppose I'll oblige.  I'm still stuck though; see the first two comments.

Comment: Move the definition of `stack-network-mode-map` *before* the `define-derived-mode` form.  Otherwise `define-derived-mode` defines `stack-network-mode-map` implicitly with a newly created keymap. `defvar` however does not change the value of variables which are already set.

Comment: @lunaryorn, would you please edit that into the answer?  That's what fixed it for good!

Comment: @vermiculus I have added this as a new answer.

Comment: It's unfortunate then that all I can give you is an upvote there.

Comment: @vermiculus I do not care for votes and reputation on my answers.

Comment: @lunaryorn it's only fair.  This is as much part of the solution as the accepted answer -- I would not have easily put together the fact that `defvar` is a little silly and `define-derived-mode` had the behavior.  At its core, upvoting is a way of saying 'thanks.'

Answer (score 3):

Move the definition of `stack-network-mode-map` before the definition of the mode. Otherwise `define-derived-mode` implicitly defines this variable, and `defvar` does not change the value of non-nil variables, so the map will be empty actually.

See [Derived Modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Derived-Modes.html):

> The new mode has its own sparse keymap, named variant`-map`. `define-derived-mode` makes the parent mode's keymap the parent of the new map, unless variant`-map` is already set and already has a parent.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a keymap but you have not used it. The variable exists but does not capture any key events.

```
(use-local-map stack-network-mode-map)
```